# The shapefiles of two different contours overlap with each other

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, contour

I tried to create two contour lines with a relatively small difference (0.5meter) on a DEM dataset. 
For example, I created an 8-meter contour(the red one) and then created an 8.5-meter(the blue one) contour. Their shapefiles overlapped with each other at the place which should be the position of 8-meter contour.
What's weirder is that I cannot select the 8.5-meter shapefile while I can select an invisible line of 8.5-meter beside its shapefile (highlighted blue line).

[image: the 8-meter contour]
[image: 8.5-meter contour]

Here's the code I used to create these contours, I set the interval as 200 so it will only draw one line:

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "D:\Arc GIS\"

arcpy.Contour_3d("Dem.tif","D:\Arc GIS\Dem,-8.shp", 200, -8)

arcpy.Contour_3d("Dem.tif","D:\Arc GIS\Dem,-8.5.shp",200, -8.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this (you defined contour_interval as 200):

according to [ArcGIS](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/contour.htm):

> Contour_3d (in_raster, out_polyline_features, contour_interval,
>   {base_contour}, {z_factor})

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "D:\Arc GIS\"

arcpy.Contour_3d("Dem.tif","D:\Arc GIS\Dem,-8.shp", -8, 0)

arcpy.Contour_3d("Dem.tif","D:\Arc GIS\Dem,-8.5.shp",-8.5, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I set interval as 200 intentionally because I just want to draw the contour at the elevation at 8. With such a big interval, no other contour will be drawn because it exceeds the band of my dem dataset.